# Disable Airplane Mode from Safe Mode Command Prompt in Win 10

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, airplane-mode

Win 10 ver 1803(os Build 17134.1) on HP Envy x360 M6
Specs https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c05315774

I made an inadvertent error.  I was running a rootkit scan in safemode and rebooted; without remembering that I was on Airplane mode and I am preset to login with a Microsoft Account.  Duh!

Now I am stuck in computer getting me to a login page that asks for my Microsoft accounts username/pwd but it cannot verify that because it is in airplane mode.  I cannot get out of it.

I have not yet figured out a way to either:
1) Turn off Airplane mode via netsh or regedit
2) To switch to login with local accounts.  (I can login to my local account via safe-mode via command prompt.  But if I go via the GUI shell on safe mode I am asked for the microsoft account it fails to recognize my local account).

Or is there a better way?

So far what I have tried:
Get to safe-mode command prompt (login as the local admin).
RegEdit hasn't helped much; I haven't found any relevant keys or any internet artilces on it.

net start wlansvc  - it starts the service.
show interface command doesn't show interfaces.  So I tried:
netsh wlan set autoconfig enabled=yes Interface="Wireless Network Controller"

Aha hears where it stops me. It gives me the message:
There is no such interface on the system

I think long time ago I renamed the Wireless Network Controller to another name like Wi-Fi or WiFi for some other testing.  Now I can't figure out how to get a list of the interface names.

Help  ????

Comment: You should be able to log into your Microsoft Account linked local profile, even while offline, due to the fact the account is still local and the password is cached.

Comment: Yes. I did think that too.  When I tried it didn't recognize my password. Even though I hadn't changed my password in a while.  I even tried changing the password by booting with the iSunShare tool and changing the password of the connected local account.  Even that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all can you help us with what kind of system are you using laptop or Desktop,

If you are using Laptop then there will be a Airplane Mode/ Network Button somewhere on the keyboard or the DVD player. Or You can also try 
Fn+Prn Scrn key to activate and activate the Airplane Mode, You can do that on the login page of windows.

and if your able to login in safe mode with admin Priveleges then follow this

Go to Regedit through Run window and reach the reg files below and modify the DWORD value in the registry key.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\RadioManagement\SystemRadioState

(Default) DWORD

0 = Off
1 = On

Comment: Editing the registry key worked in my situation. I had a persistent 'PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA' BSOD after enabling Airplane mode and crashing during some Windows updates. Booted into Safe Mode, tweaked that key, rebooted, and got back in. Thanks!

Comment: I was able to use the LazySoft Recovery Tool to login and change the registry key; but it still shows as in Airplane mode.
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\RadioManagement\SystemRadioState

(Default) DWORD

0 = Off 1 = On